# SQL Group-By and Returning Limited Results

Tags: sql

I was recently asked a SQL question in an interview.
The requirement is to find the "most enthusiastic student" in a table holding student IDs, course number, and year. The query should return the student who took the most classes per year and only return those records.(I'm sort of ignoring situations where different students take the same number of classes in a given year since I wasn't given a requirement for that. It could be that there would be other requirements to satisfy the tie so I've avoided that situation and am just focusing on getting a query to work for this particular situation where there are no equally enthusiastic students per year).

I built a small table afterwards to try to iron out this query.
My table has three fields:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
student_no    INT,
course_no     INT,
year          varchar(4));
```

(This is a really simple table. I know the year shouldn't be stored like this, etc. I don't want to get hung up on the table's format. It's just to support the exercise as simply as possible.)

And the data I created was:

```
'1', '1', '2000'
'1', '2', '2000'
'1', '3', '2000'
'2', '1', '2000'
'2', '2', '2000'
'2', '3', '2000'
'2', '4', '2000'
'1', '2', '2001'
'1', '1', '2001'
'1', '3', '2001'
'1', '4', '2001'
'2', '1', '2001'
'2', '2', '2001'
'2', '3', '2001'
```

...so that **student 2 is the most enthusiastic student for year 2000** with 4 courses** and **student 1 is the most enthusiastic student for year 2001** with 4 courses**.

```
'1', '4', '2001'
'2', '4', '2000'
```

The query I finally got to work is:

```
Select * from (
   select max(coursecount), year from
    (select student_no, count(course_no) as coursecount, year
      from students
      group by student_no, year) as internal group by year) as maxes,
        (select student_no, count(course_no) as coursecount, year
          from students
          group by student_no, year) as students
 where maxes.coursecount = students.coursecount
 and maxes.year = students.year
```

...but I have a feeling there's a better way to do this.

Could someone please show me 1) a more elegant way to do this with ANSI SQL and 2) another way to do this with analytic functions in Oracle?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you looking at?

Comment: I'm using MySQL at home so that's why I'm trying ANSI SQL but am also familiar with Oracle, just don't currently have access to an Oracle DB.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you were using SQL Server 2005+

You could try

```
;WITH Vals AS (
    SELECT year, student_no, COUNT(course_no) Cnt
    FROM students
    GROUP BY  year, student_no
 )
, RowIDS AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY year ORDER BY CNT DESC) RowID
    FROM Vals
)
  SELECT *
  FROM RowIDS 
  WHERE RowID = 1
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25dae/3)

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL you can try:

```
select year,student_no
from students
group by year,student_no
having count(*) = (
   select max( cnt ) 
   from (
     select count(*) cnt
     from students
     group by year,student_no
   ) x
  )
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/41d12/7